# How to increment all values in an array interval by a given amount in python ? Having big o as small as possible

Tags: python-3.x

I am solving a question in which I have to increase the value of each element between a given range by 1 and question has as many range as the number of elements in list.
I have done the question using two for loop but it's not effecient .
If anyone can help me to solve it by logn complexity,It would be great!!!
Thanx in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a coding service website. Show us, what you have done so far in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and you'll get help

Comment: In addition, if you have working code, a better place to get help for optimization is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/